# Question about the Monte Carlo Algortihm

Tags: monte-carlo, simulation, area

I was reading the Monte Carlo algorithm for finding the area under a curve, say $y=f(x)$.

The algorithm considers, $0\le f(x)\le M$ over the closed interval $a\le x\le b$.

My question is,that why is it necessary for $f(x)\ge 0$ for the algorithm to work why can't it simply be $|f(x)|\le M$ ?

Comment: I don't think the positiveness is necessary. Where did you find that condition?

Comment: @ShuchangZhang My book says so, also i tried finding the values of y for circles of different radii, eg, $x^2+y^2$=$9$ then for $-3\le x\le 3$ it turns out that $y$=$\sqrt(9-x^2)$ is such that $0\le y\le 3$(say) but for any circle $y\ge 0$ always.

Comment: I think the book regards $f(x)$ as a probability distribution up to a normalization constant, which requires $f(x)\geq 0$ and bounded. So for non-positive function, you can shift it to positive and simulate it. Then cancel the part of shifting and obtain the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monte Carlo integration works by randomly choosing a large number of points $(x,y)$ within a rectangle of height $M$ whose bottom side is the segment [a,b], and computing what fraction of those points lie in the region "under the curve", i.e. having $y < f(x)$. If you tried this with $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin x \ dx$ (which equals $0$), you wouldn't get any "hits" for $x < 0$, and you'd get an answer of $2$. Of course you can adjust the algorithm to take negative areas into account, but maybe the book was just trying to show the idea and didn't want to fool with the details.